# Android Voice Recorder app is crashed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, vorbis

I am working with an app that was build in Eclipse for voice recording and to play it with Giss.tv server. Now I have migrated that app code in to the Android Studio. I got many errors before successful build of this app.

Now, my code is generating apk and it is getting open in emulator as well as in device. but when I start to record voice, getting error "Unfortunately xxx has stopped" and app gets closed.

When I checked logcat for error and exception then I get below exception-

```
01-14 11:51:22.875 3711-3775/com.vorbisdemo E/art: No implementation found for int org.xiph.vorbis.encoder.VorbisEncoder.startEncodingWithQuality(long, long, float, org.xiph.vorbis.encoder.EncodeFeed) (tried Java_org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder_startEncodingWithQuality and Java_org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder_startEncodingWithQuality__JJFLorg_xiph_vorbis_encoder_EncodeFeed_2)
01-14 11:51:22.875 3711-3775/com.vorbisdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-175
                                                              Process: com.vorbisdemo, PID: 3711
                                                              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int org.xiph.vorbis.encoder.VorbisEncoder.startEncodingWithQuality(long, long, float, org.xiph.vorbis.encoder.EncodeFeed) (tried Java_org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder_startEncodingWithQuality and Java_org_xiph_vorbis_encoder_VorbisEncoder_startEncodingWithQuality__JJFLorg_xiph_vorbis_encoder_EncodeFeed_2)
                                                                  at org.xiph.vorbis.encoder.VorbisEncoder.startEncodingWithQuality(Native Method)
                                                                  at org.xiph.vorbis.recorder.VorbisRecorder$AsyncEncoding.run(VorbisRecorder.java:512)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have code from VorbisRecorder.java (https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android/blob/master/src/org/xiph/vorbis/recorder/VorbisRecorder.java)

I tried to check input values of (line no. 511)

```
case WITH_QUALITY:
                    result = VorbisEncoder.startEncodingWithQuality(sampleRate, numberOfChannels, quality, encodeFeed);
                    break;
```

and values are like shown below-

"sampleRate"=44100, "numberOfChannels"=2, "quality"=0.2, "encodeFeed"= org.xiph.vorbis.recorder.VorbisRecorder$OutputStreamEncodeFeed@19b5c49c

So I am not getting why exception is get throw here even values seems valid.

Comment: Is this VorbisRecorder a DLL by any chance? It looks like there is a library missing from your build, and it's probably a native DLL and not a plain Java JAR.

Comment: @Ewald, I am not sure if it is using DLL but I have added "jniLibs" folder in my code for ogg

Comment: I've had the same kind of issues with DLL's not being linked to my Android Studio project, it compiles, but then at runtime is unable to resolve the external functions. I see in the repo that it requires the NDK to be present and configured - I assume you've done that already. Does the "./build_jni.sh" command work?  Also - make sure you are not using ProGuard - that could also cause issues.

Comment: Yes, I found ProGuard folder "\sdk\tools\proguard". Please let me know how I can ignore it.

Comment: I think PhiLab is onto the right track there with his answer. Best wishes with the project, I haven't done native dev in Android Studio yet.

Comment: ok, np. I will go with answer of PhiLab. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure thing - in your build.gradle file, under your release section, put minifyEnabled false to make sure it doesn't run ProGuard until you've configured it properly.

Answer (score 0):

`startEncodingWithQuality` is a native function (see [here](https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android/blob/master/src/org/xiph/vorbis/encoder/VorbisEncoder.java)) and your app searches for the native implementation and does not find it.

Unfortunately, I have bad news for you: AndroidStudio does not fully support NDK development yet. I think you have two options:

- You'll find a tutorial on how to use the experimental Gradle plugin [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview).
  After you have the NDK support ready, it should work.

OR

- Add the following to your gradle file: `dependencies { compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') }` to your gradle, while `libs` is the path to [libvorbis-libogg-android/libs/](https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android/tree/master/libs)

Comment: Hi PhiLab, I read and try to follow Experimental Gradle plugin setup. But it is strictly for Gradle 2.5 and I have version 2.8, so not getting proper result. Is there any way to change version of Gradle ?

Comment: Did the first step in the guide not work? It says to modify the ``./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`` file: ``distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip``

Comment: Hi PhilLab, I have read and checked all document at "http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Introduction" and follow steps very clearly. After doing all changes, I tried to sync my project and while this process I got error "Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject". So to resolve this error, I tried to set Gradle version from 2.8 to 2.5 and try to sync project. But now it is showing message "Sync in progress" for endless time.

Comment: Make sure you have the right version of AndroidStudio (i.e. >= 1.5.1)